# Convert list to enumerated list in Groovy

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

I have a list of strings of this type:

```
list = ['AB-000 Some text', 'AB-003 Some other text', 'AB-004 Some more text']
```

How can I enumerate this list (using Groovy), i.e. get the following:

```
list = ['1. AB-000 Some text', '2. AB-003 Some other text', '3. AB-004 Some more text']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
list.withIndex().collect{ it, index -> "${index + 1}. ${it}" }
```

**UPDATE:**
(Courtesy of https://gist.github.com/michalbcz/2757630)

Or you can get fancy and actually define `collectWithIndex` method:

```
List.metaClass.collectWithIndex = { yield ->
    def collected = []
    delegate.eachWithIndex { listItem, index ->
        collected << yield(listItem, index)
    }

    return collected 
}

result = list.collectWithIndex { it, index -> "${index + 1}. ${it}" }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! In the end, I combined two of your solutions to `list.withIndex().collect { it, index -> "${index+1}. ${it}" }`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `indexed` and pass it the number to start with

```
list.indexed(1).collect { idx, s -> "$idx. $s" }
```